# Why does Private key appear password protected with no EOL?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I've a server setup which is accessed via SSH by pulling a key from an external secure server. The SSH key is not password protected however asks for a password when I try to access the server:

```
Enter passphrase for key 'my-key'
```

When I view the key using vi, it has a noeol message at the end of the file

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----

...
...
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~/.ssh/my-key" [noeol] 27L, 1798C
```

This is rectified when I append \n when copying the key. Why does a lack of EOL cause the key to look for a password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be because of the (proprietary) OPENSSH private key format, [described here](https://coolaj86.com/articles/the-openssh-private-key-format/), which includes:

- A format ID prefix
- Encryption headers
- An unused number for number of keys in the block
- An rfc4253-style ssh public key
- An private key somewhat modeled after the rfc4253 style
- A comment
- Padding for aligning private key to the blocksize